# ObjC Xcode 7 beta: Reference to <ENUM> is ambiguous

Tags: objective-c, xcode7

This is the declaration:

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    TTpixMLStatusOK,
    TTpixMLStatusError,
    TTpixMLStatusWarning, 
} TTpixMLStatus;
```

In a simplified situation (in another class)

```
NSUInteger bla = TTpixMLStatusError;
```

is flagged with: Reference to TTpixMLStatusError is ambiguous.

This is not a new code, and I am sure it was working before. 
Any idea what changed in latest Xcode versions to brake this?

There is no naming conflict, I checked this N times. Also projects are cleaned re rebuilt N times.

Comment: Have you tried to create enum with the `NS_ENUM` macro? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html

Comment: Yes, first thing I tried was NS_ENUM. Unfortunately no luck, the same error. Sorry that I forgot to mention it.